# responseAsSlurper error groovy

Tags: exception, groovy

im having problems trying to encapsulate this sentence in to a groovy function.

***-----------------------------------mi call-------------------------------***

```
sizeOfferPrices =
responseAsSlurper.Body.FlightPriceRS.PricedFlightOffers.PricedFlightOffer.OfferPrice.size();
offerAmount = getTotalPrice(sizeOfferPrices)
```

***-----------------------------my function--------------------------------***

```
def getTotalPrice (sizeOfferPrices){

    def strTravelersAssociated
    def floatImporteViaje = 0
    String [] arrTravelersAssociated
    def offerAmountTemp

        //recorremos los precios que se nos ha devuelto en la oferta
        for(i=0; i<=sizeOfferPrices-1; i++){
            //obtenemos el precio
            offerAmountTemp = responseAsSlurper.Body.FlightPriceRS.PricedFlightOffers.PricedFlightOffer.OfferPrice[i].RequestedDate.PriceDetail.TotalAmount.SimpleCurrencyPrice
            offerAmountTemp = offerAmountTemp.toFloat();

            //obtenemos los datos de los viajeros asociados , casteamos a string y splitamos para obtener array
            strTravelersAssociated = responseAsSlurper.Body.FlightPriceRS.PricedFlightOffers.PricedFlightOffer.OfferPrice[i].RequestedDate.Associations.AssociatedTraveler.TravelerReferences
            strTravelersAssociated = strTravelersAssociated.toString();
            arrTravelersAssociated = strTravelersAssociated.tokenize(" ");

            //obtenemos el numero de viajeros por oferta
            intTravelersByOffer = arrTravelersAssociated.size().toInteger();

            //realizamos la multiplicaciónd viajeros por su oferta asociada
            floatImporteViajeTemp = (offerAmountTemp * intTravelersByOffer).round(2);
            floatImporteViaje =  floatImporteViaje + floatImporteViajeTemp;
        }
        //obtenemos el precio total
        amount = floatImporteViaje.round(2);
        return amount
}
```

_________________________ERROR_________________________________________

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: no such Property
>   resposeAsSpluger

[image]

any suggestions? thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question, as currently is, will likely be closed. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

The error is unrelated to the function you've posted, because it's occurring before the function is called. Here's the code where you attempt to call the function

```
sizeOfferPrices = responseAsSlurper.Body.FlightPriceRS.PricedFlightOffers.PricedFlightOffer.OfferPrice.size();
offerAmount = getTotalPrice(sizeOfferPrices)
```

The error occurs on the first line (before `getTotalPrice` is called) because you try to access a property `responseAsSlurper` which does not exist.